# Join data from two tables and top from table 2

Tags: sql

i have this tables:

Table1:

```
id   Name
1   Example1
2   Example2
```

Table2:

```
id  Date..............
1   5.2.2014........
1   6.2.2014.........
1   6.2.2014........
2   16.1.2014.......
2   17.1.2014.......
```

And I need take id and Name from table1 and join table1.id = table2.id and from table2 take only top 1 row...
Example:

```
id    Name         Date
1     Example1   5.2.2014
2     Example2   16.1.2014
```

It is possible?

Comment: which DBMS .. MSSQL or Mysql , oracle etc ??

Comment: Define "top row", too.  Tables in SQL don't really have any inherent order to them (indices are essentially optimization details), so you get rows back in an undefined order if you leave off the `ORDER BY` clause.    It looks like you need a simple `MIN()` aggregate as some answers are showing - will the data in your tables support this sort of simple query, or are we going to need something a little more involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to filter out all but the latest row per `id`:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (partition by id order by Date desc) as rn
        ,       *
        from    Table2
        ) as t2
join    Table1 as t1
on      t1.id = t2.id
where   t2.rn = 1 -- Only latest row
```

Comment: Result is only this: 1     Example1   5.2.2014   ......And I need all resuls: 1     Example1   5.2.2014 and 
2     Example2   16.1.2014

Comment: Whoops, I forgot the `partition by` clause.  Try again!

Comment: Now i have this:  1     Example1   5.2.2014  1     Example1   5.2.2014  1     Example1   5.2.2014  and  2     Example2   16.1.2014  2     Example2   16.1.2014.......But i need only 1 record for id from table1...

Comment: That's strange... if you can reproduce the problem at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), I could have a further look.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a simple attempt would be

```
SELECT  t1.*,
        (SELECT TOP 1 t2.Date FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID t2.Date) t2Date
FROM    Table1 t1
```

If you were using SQL Server, you could use [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Something like

```
;WITH Vals AS (
            SELECT  t1.ID,
                    t1.Name,
                    t2.Date,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY t2.Date) RowID
            FROm    Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
                    Table2 t2   ON  t1.ID
    )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Vals
    WHERE   RowID = 1
```

Comment: It is ok? :   SELECT  t1.*,

Comment: Should be fine, most people though would recomend specifying the actual column names and not using `*`

Answer (score -1):

```
Select t1.id, t1.name , MIN(t2.date)
From table1 t1
Inner Join table2 t2
 On t1.id=t2.id
Group By t1.id, t1.name
```

Comment: please somebody explain problem with this solution